# Need to wait for report load completely before executing any other code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reporting-services, webforms

I have this Report on Reporting Services that I need to open only once and then execute some database updates that won't let it open again. What is happening is that the code below is executing before the report fully loads. Is there any way to wait untill it's loaded and only then execute the other code?

```
    ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
        modalPopupPrint.Show();

        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdSucess.Rows)
        {
            //Do some LINQ updates in the database here.
        }
```

Comment: Webforms. added tags already. Thanks

Comment: You can use `mutex` to lock the part of your code that you wish to wait.

Comment: @VitorReis Are you talking waiting for `ReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh` to complete, or `modalPopupPrint.Show`?

Comment: What is the value of your [AsyncRendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.asyncrendering(v=vs.100).aspx) property? What version of ReportViewer are we talking about?

Comment: @MikeC it's the refresh method